# In unbreakable why doesn't David "sense" that Elijah planned the disasters sooner?

Tags: plot-explanation, unbreakable

I know that David sensed what Elijah did at the end when they shake hands but why did it take him so long?

I think I recall he "sensed" that the man in the army jacket had a gun in his belt without coming into contact with him and while he was a good distance away from him. Why didn't he sense what Elijah had did?

Is it because his ability to see things increased throughout the movie?

Comment: I thought he brushed up against the guy in the army jacket as he was moving up the line towards his post. He had never touched Elijah before they shook hands.

Comment: Ah I think ur right. My bad. I watched it a few days ago and forgot about that. So he mustn't have come into contact with Elijah any time they met before the end?

Comment: @JackBNimble: I think you should post your comment as answer(_and answer OP's question in the comment as well_), and rake up sweet victory points :)

Comment: @JackBNimble Yes, put it down as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am fairly certain he brushed up against the guy in the army jacket as he was walking up the line to his post. His ability to sense evil in others is touch dependent. It also isn't something he actively tries to develop until later in the film.

Throughout the film he has no physical contact with Elijah until the very end. This is why he isn't able to perceive the evil things Elijah has done.